# How to clear the RAM without restart in Windows 11 properly?

Tags: windows, memory, windows-11

After using the windows 11 continuously for several days, the operating system had some(12 GB) of RAM in use instead of the 3 GB even all the programs were closed.

Is there a way(with perhaps the Command Prompt) to clear the RAM without a restart, so that the OS could be used like a Linux sever?

Comment: Why do you think you need to 'clear' it? What practical problem are you facing?

Comment: Windows already does a good job of managing memory. Users generally cannot do better.

Comment: How much memory does your system have?

Comment: @Tetsujin The system got slower, and this also correlated to the increased chance of software failure. I sometimes restart the windows before running a long simulation because of this. It's somewhat a problem, especially when I tried to run MATLAB for days.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in comments, if the machine is working, don't break it - *RAM is there to be used*.

However, I find some programs function better when memory is freed. For example, bringing a large number of ebooks into Calibre is faster when more RAM is available. Windows "garbage collection" is not always prompt, and Wagnardsoft's [Intelligent standby list cleaner (ISLC)](https://www.wagnardsoft.com/content/Intelligent-standby-list-cleaner-ISLC-v1030-Released) can make it more responsive to needs. Again, if there are no issues with free RAM, that app is not needed.

Comment: But the os does seem to be noticeable slower. I suspect there might be some types of redundancy or wrongly cached tasks there. Does windows pro or workstation fix this type of issues?

Answer (score -1):

You cannot clear the RAM since the OS is loaded into the RAM.What you can do is close down all of the apps+background apps manually from the Task Manager.

Also [click this](https://www.partitionwizard.com/partitionmanager/cmd-kill-process.html):